# Choosing variable values from a list using Do and If Loops

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, procedural-programming

```
blist = List[];

tlist=List[];

Do[
 bv1 = bv[[i]];
 tv1 = tv[[i]];
 m = M[[i]];
 result = bv1*(bv1 + tv1) - m;
 Print[result "= result"];

 If[Abs[result] < 0.01,
 blist = Append[blist, bv1];
 tlist = Append[tlist, tv1],
 Break[]],
 {i,1,100,1}]
```

I am trying to choose particular values of variables (tv1, bv1) from lists that satisfy a condition. Do loops works well to evaluate the condition but If loop is not evaluating anything.

Here, bv, tv, M are a list of numbers. The Do Loop print the "result" which is less than 0.01 (which also satisfies the If condition). But No values of bv1or tv1 are appended to the empty list. Please help. I am a beginner in Mathematica.

Comment: Instead of using Append, I tried to just Print the values of bv1 and tv1 that satisfies the condition inside the If loop, but I get no output.

Comment: I can't be certain, but it looks like: If the very first result is acceptable then it will append that and otherwise the Break will throw you out of the Do loop. Try a Print inside the top of the Do and another after the end of the If[...] and see if the Do starts, at least once, and if the first result is good enough and bails out of the Do if the first one isn't good enough. In other words, maybe you don't need the Break inside the If.

Comment: It is easy enough to include the list of numbers to your post for `tv`, `bv` and `M`. Please do so in order to create a minimal working example.

Comment: Try a similar but smaller example: `blist = List[];
tlist = List[];
bv = RandomReal[{1, 2}, 5];
tv = RandomReal[{2, 4}, 5];
M = RandomReal[{5, 10}, 5];
Do[bv1 = bv[[i]];
 tv1 = tv[[i]];
 m = M[[i]];
 result = bv1*(bv1 + tv1) - m;
 Echo[{bv[[i]], tv[[i]], M[[i]]}, "{bv, tv, M} = "];
 Echo[{bv1, tv1, m, i}, "{bv1, tv1, m, i} = "];
 Echo[result, "result = "];
 If[Abs[result] > 0.01, AppendTo[blist, bv1];
  AppendTo[tlist, tv1], Break[]];
 ,
 {i, 1, 5, 1}
 ]
Echo[bv, "bv = "];
Echo[tv, "tv = "];`

Comment: An attempt: `{blist,tlist}=First@Transpose[MapIndexed[If[Abs[#1]<0.01,{bv[[#2]],tv[[#2]]},Nothing]&,bv*(bv+tv)-M],{3,2,1}]`

Comment: Thanks @Bill, Print inside the do loop works but i  shall try after the do loop.

Comment: thanks all for the comments, i shall check and inform later.

Comment: @Syed, Why is there a Echo[ ]; multiplied after the "]" of Do loop  ? Is that inside or outside the loop ?

Comment: Actually, make a correction: Make those last items outside the loop as `tlist` and `blist` and it will show if items have been appended to those initially empty lists. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ok. Thanks,  blist and tlist instead of bv and tv ?

Comment: @Syed, your code should work but the only problem i see  when i put in my programe is : 'result' in your code gives a value (a number. For eg. result = 0.0012342 ) in output but for my programe, 'result' is shown in a curly bracket {}. i.e. result = {0.0324111}. So If condition do not evaluate it. can you point out the error in my code ?  I can also show you a photo.

Comment: I was trying to create an example based on @Bill 's comments above and I asked for concrete numbers but you haven't provided any. In your original code, there is no initialization and things are symbolic for the result. I suggest you **(1)** study the comments, and incorporate what you can to your example **(2)** provide the numbers as requested but above all **(3)** explain what you are trying to do instead of asking people to fix your code; chances are there is a better way to accomplish the task.

Comment: I am sorry, I shall edit the code and provide you the numbers.

Comment: I have got the results. Thank you all. Sorry for my  mistakes.

Comment: One comment to add : The ```Break[]``` inside the ```If``` loop takes us outside the Do loop at the first instant the condition fails. So, it is better not to use it, as suggested by @Bill. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try something like this:

```
With[{classifiers = UnitStep[Abs[bv (bv + tv) - M] - 0.01]},
 blist = Pick[bv, classifiers, 0];
 tlist = Pick[tv, classifiers, 0];
 ]
```